# Disable Spring Boot Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

**How to disable Spring Boot auto configuration.I want to disable the data source auto configuration.**

Answer (score 2):

Try this two way:

**Properties configuration**

```
    spring:
      profiles: app-profile
      autoconfigure:
        exclude:
        - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
        - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

**Class level configuration**

```
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class SpringBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }
```

Reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Comment: If you could also include a link to general guide that would be great. +1 nevertheless